# Apache pig, parse combined log using regex

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, apache-pig, quote

I use pig latin script and I tried to parse log using regex but, it returns an error while matching the double quote " . 
such as : 
ERROR 1200:   Unexpected character ' " '
the log format:

```html
118.102.255.50 - - [17/Oct/2014:00:00:29 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36"
```

while the script that I wrote:

```html
test = LOAD '/pigdata/log' as (line:chararray);
log = FOREACH test GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.(\\S+\\s+\\S+).\\s+\"(\\S+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(HTTP[^\"]+)\"\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+\"([^\"]*)\"\\s+\"(.*)\"$')) AS (address_ip: chararray, logname: chararray, user: chararray, timestamp: chararray, method: chararray, uri: chararray, proto: chararray, status: int, bytes: int, referer: chararray, userAgent: chararray);

dump log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Pig uses Java Regex, you need to escape the `"` by `\\` like this :

```
log = FOREACH test GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+.(\\S+\\s+\\S+).\\s+\\"(\\S+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(HTTP[^"]+)\\"\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+\\"([^"]*)\\"\\s+\\"(.*)\\"$')) AS (address_ip: chararray, logname: chararray, user: chararray, timestamp: chararray, method: chararray, uri: chararray, proto: chararray, status: int, bytes: int, referer: chararray, userAgent: chararray);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, problem resolved. I juste removed the back slash \ for quotes " and it works,  it appears that PIG doesn't need that, just remove the backslashes.